# Is COUNTDISTINCT base measure faster than calculated distinct measure?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a fact table and dimension table that look like this

```
​Fact {DateKey,UserKey,ActionKey,Action Count}
```

I have a user dimension table that looks like this

```
DimUser {UserKey,Name,IsActive}
```

and a date dimension table that looks like this

```
DimDate { DateKey, Week, Year}
```

I have a physical distinct count measure on the DateKey column on the measure group based of the fact table..lets call it "DATE COUNT"

Now I want to have a calculated measure called "DAILY ACTIVE USERS" which will looks like this

```
[IsDailyActive] = IIF([Measures].[DATE COUNT] >= 21, 1, 0)

[Daily Active Users] = SUM([Dim User].[User Key].[User Key].Members, [Measures].[IsDailyActive])
```

There is also another way to solve this problem w/o using the physical distinct count measure as follows

```
[HasAction] = IIF([Measures].[Action Count] > 1, 1, 0)

[DATE COUNT] = SUM([Dim Date].[DATE KEY].[DATE KEY].Members, [Measures].[HasAction])

[IsDailyActive] = IIF([Measures].[DATE COUNT] >= 21, 1, 0)

[Daily Active Users] = SUM([Dim User].[User Key].[User Key].Members, [Measures].[IsDailyActive])
```

But I'm afraid the calculated measure will be slower than the physical distinct count measure that is calculated at processing time instead of at query time. Any thoughts of which will be better performing? My fact table has billion rows!

Comment: Of course the physical measure would be faster. That said, why don't you actually try it out yourselves and let us know? :)

Comment: Is this pseudocode or mdx? (I've not been involved in creating our cubes so please excuse my ignorance)

Comment: @whytheq - a bit of both I am assuming :)

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti won't the `0`'s cause a problem? should they not all be changed to `null`s to preserve sparse cube space and block calculations?

Comment: NULL values are treated as 0 by the engine. So, I think that if the engine comes across any NULL values, it first converts that to zero and then proceeds. Thus, I can only see NULL values making things slower. But if you know that this is a bad practice, please point me to any reference. I would be happily wronged.

Comment: nulls are better for performance than 0s in the filter function coz the former will enable block computation